# can access snd-aloop microphone via ALSA but not with pipewire

Tags: alsa, microphone, pipewire, loop-device

I use an application that links my phone to my desktop as camera/microphone combo (Iriun Webcam). The application establishes a "virtual" microphone on the desktop computer via the snd-aloop and v4l2loopback kernel modules. This works well with the video, however, I cannot access the microphone with the Gnome Desktop sound configuration tools and programs that use pipewire (or pipewire-pulse) to manage sound devices, like OBS Studio or Firefox. That is, the loop device shows up but does not record anything. However, I can record audio successfully with ALSA alone via arecord or audacity (using ALSA directly); the problem seems to be that Pipewire uses an incorrect device number – the card is no. 3, and the recording device no. 1 (ALSA hw:3,1 -- and pipewire might use hw:3,0). Is there any possibility to make Pipewire recognize the loop device correctly?

Thanks for your time & effort!

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10, with the distribution's standard pipewire and ALSA packages (libpipewire is 0.3.79); pipewire-alsa is installed and the hardware sound components work fine. On request I can post the output of pw-dump or other diagnostic utilities.

Comment: You could look at `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/*-alsa-*.lua`

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.